# Intercept outputs from a Program in Windows 7

Tags: encryption, windows-7, intercept

I have an executable program which outputs data to the harddisk e.g. C:\documents.

I need some means to intercept the data in Windows 7 before they get to the hard drive. Then I will encrypt the data and send it back to the harddisk. Unfortunately, the .exe file does not support redirection command i.e. > in command prompt. Do you know how I can achieve such a thing in any programming language (c, c++, JAVA, php).

The encryption can only be done **before** the plain data is sent to the disk not after.

Any ideas most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is virtually impossible in general. Many programs write to disk using memory-mapped files. In such a scheme, a memory range is mapped to (part of) a file. In such a scheme, writes to file can't be distinguished from writes to memory. A statement like `p[OFFSET_OF_FIELD_X] = 17;` is a logically write to file. Furthermore, the OS will keep track of the synchronization of memory and disk. Not all logical writes to memory are directly translated into physical writes to disk. From time to time, at the whim of the OS, dirty memory pages are copied back to disk.

Even in the simpler case of `CreateFile/WriteFile`, there's little room to intercept the data on the fly. The closest you could achieve is the use of Microsoft Detours. I know of at least one snakeoil encyption program (WxVault, crapware shipped on Dells) that does that. It repeatedly crashed my application in the field, which is why my program unpatches any attempt to intercept data on the fly. So, not even such hacks are robust against programs that dislike interference.